# Android Removing an element from a CollapsingToolbarLayout breaks the adjustResize option

Tags: android, imageview, android-softkeyboard, android-progressbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a simple fragment which uses the combination CoordinatorLayout + AppBarLayout + CollapsingToolbarLayout to show a collapsible ImageView  and a ProgressBar at the top of the fragment which works perfectly

In the fragment I also have an EditText wrapped in a NestScrollView and a fix "save" button at the bottom. Everything is wrapped in a main RelativeLayout.

When the fragment load I make visible the ProgressBar in the CollapsingToolbarLayout and when in the background the image has finished processing I fill the ImageView.

Now, when the user wants to edit the EditText the keyboard shows up and and usually the button is pushed upward so that it is still visible, this by adding adjustResize in the activity tag (AndroidManifest file)

This works when I do not have a ProgressBar. If I

```
1) make visible the Progress bar
2) Wait for the processing to finish
3) hide the ProgressBar
4) Fill the ImageView
```

When the user Edit the EditText the save button is NOT pushed upward and is hidden by the keyboard.

If I

```
1) make visible the Progress bar
2) Wait for the processing to finish
3) DONT hide the ProgressBar
4) Fill the ImageView
```

In that case yes the save button at the bottom is pushed upward when the user edits the EditText

Is that a bug ?